# Is the inverse of an isomorphisim function isomorphic?

Tags: abstract-algebra

Say $F$ is an isomorphic function. Then by definition it is a bijective homomorphisim and has an inverse $F^{-1}$. But is the INVERSE isomorphic by defn?

Wikpedia doesn't address this very clearly.

Thank you!

Comment: (Just a note that "isomorphic function" is not grammatically correct. A function can be an isomorphism, or a homomorphism but it can't be "isomorphic" or "homomorphic".)

Comment: Yes, but not by definition. The fact that the inverse is a homomorphism (of what, by the way? You've got to provide the context here) should be proven. It's usually easy, but we can't take it for granted.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, because the inverse is a homomorphism, which you can check.

---

Explicitly, for $a,b\in G$ we have $F(F^{-1}(a)F^{-1}(b))=F(F^{-1}(a))F(F^{-1}(b))=ab=F(F^{-1}(ab))$.

Now, $F$ is injective, so we're done.

---

We also have used that a function is invertible iff it's bijective.